# Unkown column in field list (PHP + MySQL/PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

I have already tried out various solutions, but it still gives me the error displayed below - I am out of ideas (I also tried replacing the ".$_SESSION['plz']." - part with a simple number, but didn't change anything:

```
$profilequery = "SELECT teacher.teacher_id, teacher.plz, teacher.ort,  
teacher.teacherprename, teacher.teachername, hours_week.hours_week, teacher.day_times, 
teacher.grade, teacher.study, teacher.references, teacher_subjects.qualification, 
teacher_subjects.subjectgrade, teacher_subjects.subjectqualification, 
ABS (teacher.plz - ".$_SESSION['plz'].") AS distance FROM (
(
SELECT teacher.teacher_id, teacher.plz, teacher.ort,  
teacher.teacherprename, teacher.teachername, hours_week.hours_week, teacher.day_times, 
teacher.grade, teacher.study, teacher.references, teacher_subjects.qualification, 
teacher_subjects.subjectgrade, teacher_subjects.subjectqualification FROM teacher LEFT JOIN
teacher_subjects
ON
teacher.teacher_id = teacher_subjects.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN
hours_week
ON
teacher.hours_id = hours_week.hours_id WHERE teacher.plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' 
AND teacher_subjects.status_id = '1' ORDER BY teacher.plz LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL (
SELECT teacher.teacher_id, teacher.plz, teacher.ort,  
teacher.teacherprename, teacher.teachername, hours_week.hours_week, teacher.day_times, 
teacher.grade, teacher.study, teacher.references, teacher_subjects.qualification, 
teacher_subjects.subjectgrade, teacher_subjects.subjectqualification FROM teacher LEFT JOIN
teacher_subjects
ON
teacher.teacher_id = teacher_subjects.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN
hours_week
ON
teacher.hours_id = hours_week.hours_id WHERE teacher.plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' 
AND teacher_subjects.status_id = '1' ORDER BY teacher.plz LIMIT 10
)
) AS a
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10";
```

And it throws this at me:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'plz' in 'field list'' in ..

I really don't see anything wrong here, does anyone perhaps have an idea of what could be responsible for the problem? I am thankful for any help!

EDIT: Deleted the "teacher." and "teacher_subjects." part in the queries (also tried only deleting it in the main query or the sub queries):

```
$profilequery = "SELECT teacher_id, plz, ort,  
teacherprename, teachername, hours_week, day_times, 
grade, study, references, qualification, 
subjectgrade, .subjectqualification, 
ABS (teacher.plz - ".$_SESSION['plz'].") AS distance FROM (
(
SELECT teacher_id, plz, ort,  
teacherprename, teachername, hours_week, day_times, 
grade, study, references, qualification, 
subjectgrade, .subjectqualification FROM teacher LEFT JOIN
teacher_subjects
ON
teacher.teacher_id = teacher_subjects.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN
hours_week
ON
teacher.hours_id = hours_week.hours_id WHERE teacher.plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' 
AND teacher_subjects.status_id = '1' ORDER BY teacher.plz LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL (
SELECT teacher_id, plz, ort,  
teacherprename, teachername, hours_week, day_times, 
grade, study, references, qualification, 
subjectgrade, .subjectqualification FROM teacher LEFT JOIN
teacher_subjects
ON
teacher.teacher_id = teacher_subjects.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN
hours_week
ON
teacher.hours_id = hours_week.hours_id WHERE teacher.plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' 
AND teacher_subjects.status_id = '1' ORDER BY teacher.plz LIMIT 10
)
) AS a
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10";
```

And it throws this:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'lehrer_id' in field list is ambiguous'

Now I guess it has something to do with the LEFT JOIN part (before it worked with this part, with only selecting `plz` and `lehrer_id`. I also tried putting the `LEFT JOIN` part at the very end (after the ALL UNION part) but it still throws an error.

EDIT 2: Solved it! -> had to give the queries as well as the `LEFT JOIN`s unique names (`as b` etc) and then refer to them correctly  ->

```
$profilequery = "SELECT n.teacher_id, n.plz, n.ort,  
n.teacherprename, n.teachername, n.hours_week, n.day_times, 
n.grade, n.study, n.qualification, 
n.subjectgrade, n.subjectqualification, 
ABS (n.plz - ".$_SESSION['plz'].") AS distance FROM (
(
SELECT b.teacher_id, b.plz, b.ort,  
b.teacherprename, b.teachername, sw.hours_week, b.day_times, 
b.grade, b.study lf.qualification, 
lf.subjectgrade, lf.subjectqualification FROM teacher as b LEFT JOIN
teacher_subjects as lf
ON
teacher.teacher_id = teacher_subjects.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN
hours_week as sw
ON
b.hours_id = sw.hours_id WHERE b.plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' 
AND lf.status_id = '1' ORDER BY b.plz LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL (
SELECT b.teacher_id, b.plz, b.ort,  
b.teacherprename, b.teachername, sw.hours_week, b.day_times, 
b.grade, b.study lf.qualification, 
lf.subjectgrade, lf.subjectqualification FROM teacher as b LEFT JOIN
teacher_subjects as lf
ON
teacher.teacher_id = teacher_subjects.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN
hours_week as sw
ON
b.hours_id = sw.hours_id WHERE b.plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' 
AND lf.status_id = '1' ORDER BY b.plz LIMIT 10
)
) AS n
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See updated post above (EDIT 2) -> had to give the queries as well as the LEFT JOINs unique names (as b etc) and then refer to them correctly

Answer (score 1):

Your subqueries must attach `plz` column or it will not be seen in main query, so:

```
$profilequery = "SELECT teacher_id, ABS (plz - ".$_SESSION['plz'].") AS distance FROM (
(
SELECT teacher_id, plz FROM teacher WHERE plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' ORDER BY teacher.plz LIMIT 10
) UNION ALL (
SELECT teacher_id, plz FROM teacher WHERE plz >= '".$_SESSION['plz']."' ORDER BY plz DESC
LIMIT 10
)
) AS a
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This solved the problem of my snippet, I forgot to include the "plz" there. I still have the same error in my original query and it also includes "plz" in the subqueries :(. I will post it above, perhaps you have an idea for that too? Nevertheless, thank you! And yes, I am really not that experienced/skilled (yet) :<.

Comment: Your new query is very very strange. Why do you have `SELECT SELECT` one after another? It should be error. And why in your main query you use `teacher.plz` and so on ? Main query is from subqueries and there should be only column name `plz` or alias `a.plz`

Comment: Thanks again (!), I will revamp that tomorrow. To be honest I have never used subqueries before and the subqueries with the ALL UNION was a tip I adopted from another site - basically I just wanted to use the ABS part for selecting the nearest plz, and the ALL UNION part including the subqueries is for improving the performance according to that site. The double select was a typo - sorry!

Comment: Hello nospor, I tried various things now; deleted the `teacher.` and `teacher_subjects.` in the main query and in the sub queries, leading to  "columns are ambigous" (see above, updated new code). Now since it worked before (without the LEFT JOIN part, selecting only `lehrer_id` and `plz`) it has something to do with the positioning of the LEFT JOINs though I have also tried other positionings, but everytime an error. According to a manual the LEFT JOIN can be inside the sub query, so I don't know where to put it else, even more because the other placements (e.g. at the very end) didn't work

Comment: That's good it works now. I was on conference all day and I couldn't check this earlier.